# MaskedEditExtender, dates and Globalization

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, maskededitextender

I want to use the MaskedEditExtender to mask short dates. The problem is that I want to mask the field depending on the user language settings. 
This is working for a lot of cases, but for example for Latvian Culture (with format 9999.99.99. ) is not working.

```
<cc1:MaskedEditExtender  ID="MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server" AutoComplete="True" MaskType="Date" TargetControlID="myTextbox" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="True" 
   OnInvalidCssClass="myInvalidCss" OnFocusCssClass="myOnFocusClass" Mask="99/99/9999" >
</cc1:MaskedEditExtender>
```

Is there a simple way to set the Mask property with the user culture mask format? 
Am I missing something to do this easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the extender won't recognize Latvian culture, but try looking at the overrides provided, such as CultureDateFormat and CultureDecimalPlaceholder.  More info at the [AJAX Control Toolkit sample website](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx).

**EDIT:** Response to OP's comments:

I have not idea if this works, but it looks like you can get the short date format for a culture from the CultureInfo class, like this.

```
string shortDateFormat = 
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern.aspx) for examples.

Comment: It does not recognize the latvian culture because I have "hardcoded" the Mask Value (Mask="99/99/9999")

Comment: Is there a reason you must have the Mask Value hardcoded?  Could you just assign it based on when the user arrives to the page and what culture s/he is in?

Comment: I should do that. and that's the question, how can I do that? thanks for your answer

Comment: I replaced by hand with RegEx the ShortDatePattern to get the needed mask string from, i.e. dd/MM/yyyy to 99/99/9999. There should be a easier solution.